# Grails and PlayORM

Tags: grails, log4j, dependencies, playorm

I am sorry for messy/complex description and constant editing of the question, but I am yet to pinpoint the root issue.

I am having difficulties using PlayORM  with Grails:
1. There is a dependency conflict which I might have resolved by removing "logback-classic.jar" from BuildPath and "/lib" folder, but keeping "commons-logging". See below for details of the issue.
2. Now I am getting some strange PlayORM exceptions which I think are likely due to removed dependencies:

```
| Loading Grails 2.2.1
| Configuring classpath.
| Environment set to development.....
| Packaging Grails application.....
| Running Grails application
| Error 2013-06-18 10:38:31,057 [Thread-8] ERROR plugins.DefaultGrailsPlugin  - Cannot generate controller logic for scaffolded class class nosql.Transaction. It is not a domain class!
| Server running. Browse to http://localhost:8080/gibb
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure scanning class(see chained exception)=class com.alvazan.orm.api.z8spi.meta.DboTableMeta
    at com.alvazan.orm.layer0.base.MyClassAnnotationDiscoveryListener.scanClass(MyClassAnnotationDiscoveryListener.java:50)
.......
**Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure scanning field=private java.lang.String com.alvazan.orm.api.z8spi.meta.DboTableMeta.columnFamily for class=DboTableMeta
    at com.alvazan.orm.impl.meta.scan.ScannerForClass.inspectField(ScannerForClass.java:209)
    at com.alvazan.orm.impl.meta.scan.ScannerForClass.scanFields(ScannerForClass.java:202)
    at com.alvazan.orm.impl.meta.scan.ScannerForClass.scanSingle(ScannerForClass.java:122)
    at com.alvazan.orm.impl.meta.scan.ScannerForClass.addClass(ScannerForClass.java:80)
    at com.alvazan.orm.layer0.base.MyClassAnnotationDiscoveryListener.scanClass(MyClassAnnotationDiscoveryListener.java:48)
    ... 107 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class=class com.alvazan.orm.impl.meta.data.MetaClassSingle has two fields that have @NoSqlId annotation.  One of them may be in a superclass.  The two fields are=private java.lang.String com.alvazan.orm.api.z8spi.meta.DboTableMeta.columnFamily and=private java.lang.String com.alvazan.orm.api.z8spi.meta.DboTableMeta.columnFamily
    at com.alvazan.orm.impl.meta.scan.ScannerForClass.processIdFieldWorks(ScannerForClass.java:253)
    at com.alvazan.orm.impl.meta.scan.ScannerForClass.inspectFieldImpl(ScannerForClass.java:220)
    at com.alvazan.orm.impl.meta.scan.ScannerForClass.inspectField(ScannerForClass.java:207)
    ... 111 more**
```

Note:

---

Initial problem:
Basically I got following error messages when doing "run-app" or "test-app" on Grails:

```
| Loading Grails 2.2.1
| Configuring classpath
| Error SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
| Error SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/saasbook/Dropbox/Projects/GrailsWorkSpace/gibb/lib/logback-classic-1.0.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
| Error SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/saasbook/.grails/ivy-cache/org.grails/grails-plugin-log4j/jars/grails-plugin-log4j-2.2.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
```

The app would run, but I would get a PlayORM exception when trying to flush the object to database:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Entity type=nosql.Transaction was not scanned and added to meta information on startup.  It is either missing @NoSqlEntity annotation or it was not in list of scanned packages
```

Note: "Transaction.java" class does have @NoSqlEntity and is part of "nosql" package along with "Persistance.java".

---

The initial question:

My grails app produces hundreds of `DEBUG o.c.g.g.i.s.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver` statements when I try to "run-app" or "test-app" or even "clean". The app runs from eclipse, but tests do not.

Important detail is - i checkout the app from local git repository and the original app runs perfectly fine on the same machine.

---

Response to comments:
 1. The tests simply did not run.
 2. I did not change anything in the log4j settings.
 3. After posting this question I ran the original copy of the app (in different directory) and it produced the same garbage as the first one. I though the problem is grails saving app settings in ~/.grails/2.2.1/projects/{myProjectName} but it persists even with a single "version-location" of the app.

Comment: Can you put more details on what's the error in your tests? Did you changed anything in the log4j settings?

Comment: Question may be related to [this](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPLOGBACK-3) defect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question was resolved offline by passing in the ClassLoader of Transaction.class since grails was playing classloading games and playorm was int he parent classloader, Transaction.class was not visible in the classloader that loaded playorm.

Answer (score 0):

You are having multiple issues here all in one question(looks like 3 separate issues).  Let's do one of the easier ones first

> Error SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings. | Error
>   SLF4J: Found binding in
>   [jar:file:/home/saasbook/Dropbox/Projects/GrailsWorkSpace/gibb/lib/logback-classic-1.0.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
>   | Error SLF4J: Found binding in
>   [jar:file:/home/saasbook/.grails/ivy-cache/org.grails/grails-plugin-log4j/jars/grails-plugin-log4j-2.2.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]

This is simply because of the way SLF4J works, you are not allowed different jars with StaticLoggerBinder.class.  SLF4J can run with log4j under it OR commons OR jdk OR logback(which I prefer the most and most people prefer) OR your grails-plugin-log4j which seems kind of odd.  That is BELOW.  Above it, any 3rd party libraries you suck may use log4j or commons or any library and as long as you have the SLF4j adapters AND remove the log4j.jar and the commons.jar, all will log to whatever logging system you put below.  In the above statement you provided you had to below providers logback-classic which would use the logback.xml file for logging configuration of all logging(log4j, commons, etc) and the other is grails-plugin-log4j which would have it's own logging configuration file...not logback.xml.  To resolve that one, just make sure you have the jar of the one you want...we use the logback one.

Next Two Issue's are probably related

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Entity type=nosql.Transaction was
>   not scanned and added to meta information on startup.  It is either
>   missing @NoSqlEntity annotation or it was not in list of scanned
>   packages

I am betting on a classloading issue here.  If for instance Transaction(1).class was scanned but then Transaction(2).class is passed into entityManager.put(tx), then you will get this failure.  Is grails doing byte code manipulation on Transaction.java as this line looks suspicious...

```
ERROR plugins.DefaultGrailsPlugin  - Cannot generate controller logic for scaffolded class class nosql.Transaction. It is not a domain class!
```

I am going to look a little deeper as we are trying to get better exceptions when classloading issues occur as well.  I am not sure what tricks grails is doing with classloading either.

Answer (score 0):

ok, so the first question on the classlaoding issue, there is special logs in there for this issue that go live when debug level logging is enabled only.  It captures how it got into that code twice.  One interesting piece of code is in ScannerForClass.processIdFieldWorks in which this exists

```
if(field.equals(existingField) && log.isWarnEnabled())
```

and your code should have taken that path but did not.  Perhaps, you are not logging warn logs or the configuration from that binding you use for SLF4j is not making it there soooooo....I just checked in a change to playorm to remove that.  If your field is not equal to existingField based on the toStrings, then it is definitely a classloading issue and I will add more logs to possibly help in determination of how that class is being loaded twice.

Make sure you are logging at the debug level as well so it doesn't log null as the stack trace of the first call in. (basically two calls on DboTableMeta happened into this method which should never happen as there is only one field with @NoSqlId....well, only one is allowed)

thanks,
Dean

Comment: Ok, so thus far I did:
1. Remove the "logback-classic" and solved the logger conflict.
2. Added "debug 'com.alvazan'" setting in log4j section of the "Config.groovy" and did not get the "two fields exception".
However I got the original exception again:
"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Entity type=nosql.Transaction was not scanned and added to meta information on startup.  It is either missing @NoSqlEntity annotation or it was not in list of scanned packages"

Any ideas? I can provide the code for "Transaction" class.

p.s. The last commit I see for playorm@github is from "Jun 14, 2013".

Comment: odd, sorry stackoverflow seems to be sending mail slower than usual or I didn't notice this post until now.  also, shoot, I must have committed but not pushed my changes.  I will do that tomorrow.  Send me the Transaction.java just in case though it is either byte code now or it is classloading since you already have the @NoSqlEntity annotation on Transaction.java

Comment: I can't think of an easier way to debug this.  Basically, at scan time, playorm creates a map reading from the annotations.  When you do a put(I assume you are doing a put when you get this?), it looks in the map and this class file is not there.  In eclipse debugger step into the put method and look at the variable holding that class when playorm gets it, then look in the Map and that class should be there but both will have different ids which means you have two Transaction classes loaded via different classloaders...is your jar being included twice.

Comment: also, I checked in all my changes were posted so there is a change on June 19th BUT this change won't help your current situation.

Comment: can you post the stack trace so I can give you better/more info on debugging this?

Comment: make sure you post a comment after editing your post as I am only notified of comments and posts not edits.

Comment: How can I send you my code? Just post it? Your stack profile has no email address and I emailed you at dean@xsoftware.biz but not sure you check this address. My email is listed on my profile.

Comment: "MetaClass metaClass = metaInfo.getMetaClass(cl);" gets "null" which I understand means it has no meta on the "nosql.Transaction" class.
Which "map" are you referring to? "metaInfo"?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32026/discussion-between-dash-and-dean-hiller)

Answer (score 0):

For the issue

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Entity type=nosql.Transaction was not scanned and added to meta information on startup. It is either missing @NoSqlEntity annotation or it was not in list of scanned packages
```

The reason may be that, there is no nosql.Persistence class in your classpath. See relevant FAQ at http://buffalosw.com/wiki/FAQ/

Comment: Thanks, but I did check for that. nosql.Persistence exists.